# Java proxy issues - Connection Timed Out

Tags: java, proxy

I'm writing a web scraper in Java but I'm behind a proxy server and it's making things very difficult.

This is the connection code:

```
public void scrape(String url, String filename) throws Exception {
    this.url = url;
    this.filename = filename;

    System.out.println("Scraping " + url);
    System.out.println("Saving to \"" + this.filename + "\"");

    try {
        makeConnection();
        createStream();
        writeToFile();
        System.out.println("Scrape was successful");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void makeConnection() throws Exception {
    // Set proxy info
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

    URL address = new URL(url);
    connection  = address.openConnection();
}
```

This is the output:

```
Scraping http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/northern_ireland/rss.xml
Saving to "../rss/northern_ireland.xml"
Error: Connection timed out
```

Is there a better way of setting the proxy settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the java.net.Proxy class introduced in Java 1.5...
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html

A brief writeup of how it is used can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the system's proxy settings aren't configured as you'd expected. Try explicitly setting the JVM system properties `http.proxyPort`, `http.proxyHost`, and `http.nonProxyHosts`.